# Copy rows from one sheet to another based on cell contents

Tags: string, excel, vba, conditional-statements, copy-paste

I am trying to copy rows containing specific cell with input i.e. "Slavi" to a sheet named "Slavi", "John" to a sheet "John" while making sure I do not overwrite row over row in the new sheet.

I have multiple sheets containing one column with names about , and i want to go through all the sheets, find all the data for "Slavi" and copy it to sheet "Slavi", all the data for "John" copy to the sheet "john".

Each sheet is for different project and in rows I have taks assigned to specific person so I want to be able to extract all tasks for all projects for one person into sheet with that persons name.

Thank you

Comment: It is a problem, because with 3-D reference (named range including data from multiple sheets) you can use only small set of functions. So it will be difficult to accomplish without using VBA. Only can imagine first combine all data into one sheet and then use this sheets range as a datasource.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your spreadsheet looked like you could try using a PivotTable to help you solve this quickly.

If you're using Excel 2008 or greater, create a basic pivot table showing the name (i.e. John, Slavi, etc) and a count of records and then double click on each of the names to open their data in a new sheet.